Unable to know why angles have different values?
When drawing some line segments from the family $y=kx$, where k is real integer, I noticed that the lines $xk_i$,$xk_{i+1}$ have larger angle compared to pairs of lines when k is larger. To explain more, observe the angle between the lines where $k=1$ and $k=2$, compare this angle with one between lines where $k=4$ and $k=5$. The later pair have smaller angle.
(A) Why are the angles of different values even though the difference in $k$ is the same? I expected that angles between the different lines would be the same if difference in $k$ is constant.
(B) Is there a linear relationship y=kx+b that produces such equal angles?


Measuring a slant by dividing a circle into even arcs (angle) is simply a different mechanism the measuring a slant by a ratio steepness of units of rise over units of run (slope).  There's no reason that they should be linearly related.  That said there isn't really a reason we should define "slant" as on over the other.

There are infinitely many positive integers and each one is the slope of a line between $0$ and $90$ degrees from the axis. In order to fit all those lines in there, the angles between them have to become arbitrarily small. What kind of equal angles do you want? You can only fit a certain number of them in one quadrant.

@DavidK, I was only wondering why small k values result small angle and large k value results in large angle between consecutive lines.

Actually it’s large angles between small $k$ and small angles between large $k$. There are only a few really small $k$ values, but infinitely many large ones, so it wouldn’t work the way you wrote.

By the way, the angle from $k=2$ to $k=7$ equals the angle from $k=1$ to $k=2$. The next line at the same change of angle is in the second quadrant and $k=-11/2.$ It is possible to find a set of lines at equal angle differences and rational slopes if that’s what you want.

@DavidK, you are correct, I was in a hurry. The wording in the question is probably more accurate. Your last comment is not clear for me. Thank you.

In my last comment, I observed that if you look at the lines $y=x,$ $y=2x,$ $y=7x,$ and $y=-\frac{11}2x,$ the angle between each pair of lines is the same. This may not be relevant to your question; I just thought it is interesting that if you really want the angles to all be equal you can make it happen, though you eventually have to use negative numbers and fractions.

@DavidK, as a matter of fact, this is a very interesting observation. I will study it. Thank you for pointing it out. I am surprised that what may look simple like y=kx has many points of interest! Thanks again.

(A)
Note that the slope $k=\tan\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the line and the $x$-axis.
For two different $k$ values (say $k_1$ and $k_2$), the angle between the two lines $\theta_0$ is given by the formula
$$
\theta_0 = \arctan\,\!\left|\frac{k_1-k_2}{1+k_1k_2}\right|\!
$$
So even though the difference $|k_1-k_2|$ is the same, the denominator $|1+k_1k_2|$ is larger, resulting in a smaller angle.
(B) Yes, just parametrize the line as $y=x\tan\theta$.
